# Error in Skeletonization and Skeleton Pruning

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I was trying to run the skeletonization and skeleton pruning software from
[skeletonization and skeleton pruning](https://sites.google.com/site/xiangbai/softwareforskeletonizationandskeletonpru) 
and getting the following errors. I used matlab 2015a .Authors claimed that it runs on matlab 7.0. Please help me to correct it.i just want to see the output. Anyone can suggest a pseudocode for Skeletonization and Skeleton Pruning in simple way?

```
Error in SkeletonGrow1 (line 42)
                skltn(i,j) = CheckSkeleton1(bw,dist,lab,i,j,ro,mark);

Error in div_skeleton_new (line 51)
bw=SkeletonGrow1(I0,ro,mark);

Error in Test (line 6)
[bw,I0,x,y,x1,y1,aa,bb]=div_skeleton_new(4,1,bw,15);
```

Comment: please show your code also

Comment: code is downloaded from https://sites.google.com/site/xiangbai/softwareforskeletonizationandskeletonpru

Comment: ok but (1) to help people need to know exactly what these line numbers (42), (51), ... refer to (2) its considered a low quality question if it contains only links and no code. if those links go bad then the question and answers are useless in the future.

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/xiangbai/BaiSkeletonPruningDCE.zip is the exact link

Answer (score 0):

first two errors are due to same function (CheckSkeleton1). The number of arguments are different in both calls. Tweek it, do check readme file or contact author.